# not able to use xrandr after booting ubuntu tablet with nomodeset

Tags: 14.04, xrandr, nomodeset, display-rotation

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 in my intel-z3735f baytrail tablet. I can boot this device and get the desktop only with nomodeset parameter.(When booted without nomodeset getting blank screen) But when I boot in this mode I am not able to use xrandr utility to rotate my desktop. I urgently need to rotate my screen, Thanks in advance for the help.

Below is the log I am getting on running command xrand from terminal.

```
sanj@sanj-laptop:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 1280, current 800 x 1280, maximum 800 x 1280
default connected primary 800x1280+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x1280       77.0* 
sanj@sanj-laptop:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on my laptop. It has Intel i5-7300hq and an Nvidia 1050Ti. I have been running the open source drivers which had the `nomodeset` option. The fix was to remove the `nomodeset` option but add `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"`.

Note that when I was running the Nvidia proprietary drivers on a previous installation, I still had to add the `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"` despite the `nomodeset` parameter not being there. Otherwise the laptop had problems if I elected to switch to the Intel iGPU from the driver/PRIME settings, like the laptop not shuting down.

There are some more information on [this post](https://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html). For example here's a command to suggest what Windows acpi setting you may need to use for your device to work:

```
$ sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT | grep -i 'windows ' | sort | tail -1
Windows 2015
```

As you see actually I am being suggested another value from the one that fixes the problem, so feel free to experiment if you can (removing tail from that command will show other available options).